# How to recover hard disk partition

Tags: toshiba-laptop

Laptop was slow so I tried to be smart and do factory reset. Picked the option to delete hard disk including partition without backing up. On laptop, laptop ask for system file. Don't have it.

Don't know what to do please help. I bet I deleted windows and also don't have the disk.

Comment: I sincerely apologise. Wanted to relief stress instead became foolish. Should respect everyone since im asking for help and not ask with childish language for it sounds like i am a child and not understand.

Comment: You can download the W10 iso from their site (if you're using Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to reacquire the installation media from Torrent or Toshiba, but to answer your question, Testdisk (which you can find on any decent Linux Recovery/Rescue Distro) can scan and often find and fix partitions.